# How to know the status of rolling upgrade of deployment in Kubernetes using fabric8 java client API?

Tags: java, kubernetes, fabric8

I am doing a rolling upgrade of specififc container of deployment using the fabric8 java client API

```java
client.apps().deployments().inNamespace(..)
       .withName(..)
       .rolling()
       .updateImage(...);
```

When observing k8s I can see the new pod being created and after the old one deleted as expected. How can I know the status of the upgrade programmatically?

I need to return response whether the upgrade succeeded or failed.

Answer (score 1):

To check what is happening with deployment you can use Watcher:

```
client.apps().deployments().inNamespace("default").watch(new Watcher<Deployment>() {
  @Override
  public void eventReceived(Action action, Deployment resource) {
    // Do stuff depending upon action
  }

  @Override
  public void onClose(KubernetesClientException cause) {

  }
});
```

[Action](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/c24152096f1a0438be1cd4978bea23a8dc185334/kubernetes-client/src/main/java/io/fabric8/kubernetes/client/Watcher.java#L46) is an enum, so you can check for `ERROR` and raise an exception:

```
enum Action {
    ADDED, MODIFIED, DELETED, ERROR
  }
```

[Here](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/blob/master/doc/CHEATSHEET.md#deployment) you can find more examples on what you can do with deployments